# Composer downloads the package and put in the vendor map but the service provider doesn't recognize it laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I forked an api handler from git that I need to update to be laravel 6 ([api handler that i forked what is not laravel 6 compatible](https://github.com/marcelgwerder/laravel-api-handler)) compatible but I keep getting composer errors

So when I run `composer update` it install the package from the git and put it correctly on in the vendor folder. what works fine then I add the class to the `config/app.php` like this

```
'providers'       => [
    Name\ApiHandler\ApiHandlerServiceProvider::class,
],
```

what will throw this error in laravel

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
Class 'Name\ApiHandler\ApiHandlerServiceProvider' not found
```

so far I have tried:

1. `composer clear-cache`
2. `rm -rf .cache/composer/*`
3. clear the bootstrap composer
4. delete `composer.lock`
5. delete the `vendor`

and then after that `composer update` but it keeps throwing the error. But when I am in mine editor and go to the `config/app.php` and click on `Name\ApiHandler\ApiHandlerServiceProvider::class,` while holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> it finds the class and goes to the vendor map so mine idea shows that the class is correctly imported

this is how the composer.json looks of the laravel project

```
"repositories": [
{
  "type":"package",
  "package": {
    "name": "name/laravel-api-handler",
    "version":"dev-laravel-6",
    "source": {
      "url": "https://github.com/name/laravel-api-handler",
      "type": "git",
      "reference":"branch name"
    }
  }
}
],
"require": {
  "name/laravel-api-handler": "dev-laravel-6",
},
```

the api handler composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "name\\ApiHandler\\": "src"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "name\\ApiHandler\\ApiHandlerServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
},
```

the map structure is `vendor/name/laravel-api-handler/src`

also the the custom package doesnt show up in the `Discovered Package` when running `Composer update` or `Composer install`

Am I missing something because I cant figure out what is going wrong

Comment: As I can see, this package is outdated, and not updated recently. Better idea is to avoid this package.

Comment: yes I know that why I forked the package and updated it in this case but I can not get composer to work

Comment: Did you change the namespaces of all the files in the package to a new namespace? So that `Name\ApiHandler\ApiHandlerServiceProvider` Is actually in the `Name\ApiHandler` namespace and not in the old one. It might be that it just doesn't get autoloaded at all. Im pretty sure you can do `composer dumpauto -vvv` to get some more details about what's being loaded in.

Comment: it reads the composer.json file but doesnt load in the package i also rechecked all the name spaces  are correctly replaced all the files in the vendor have the namespace `Name\ApiHandler` only the `Name\ApiHandler\ApiHandlerServiceProvider` in the `config/app,php` is it set like this what mine idea shows that it correctly goes to that vendor map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing research to editing custom packages into your project apparently composer doesn't autoload `"type":"package"` what is not mentioned in there documentation anywhere. [link where it get explained](http://blog.pepa.info/php-html-css/composer/composer-not-autoloading-your-package/)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it,

- remove the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. Then run again.
- Run below commands one by one

  ```
  composer dump-autoload

  php update
  ```

Comment: After doing `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*` and then running `composer dump-autoload` it return an error  `In ProviderRepository.php line 208:`
`Class 'Name\ApiHandler\ApiHandlerServiceProvider' not found`

Answer (score 0):

Import the ApiHandler facade into your classes:-

> use ApiHandler\Facades\ApiHandlerServiceProvider;

On top

Comment: its imported to the classes where It can recognize the class and find it, it just that laravel provider can not find the service profider because I assume that composer doesnt load them into the autoload and I geuss that is the reason that laravel cant find the class in the service profider

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove/rename your vendor folder. Then do `composer install`. Then please check again. If that doesn't work, do `composer update`. Not sure about what is happening under hood, but `composer update` did the trick in my case.